# JavaScript inheritance (infinite loop when using superclass function)

Tags: javascript, oop

I am viewing Tuts+ OO JavaScript training: The way they do prototypical inheritance looks like:

```
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

But why cant I do just (without object create)

```
Employee.prototype = Person.prototype;
```

The 2nd will give an infinite loop: http://jsfiddle.net/VMqSy/

Why? Console logging the prototypes tells me that the 1 with `Object.create()` will give Employee.prototype 1 more level of `__proto__` which is the `Person.prototype`, I think

Comment: What is the difference between the two lines?

Comment: Did you mean `Employee.prototype = Person.prototype;` (from the fiddle)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do (as shown in the fiddle)

```
Employee.prototype = Person.prototype;
```

then `Employee` will not be a subclass of `Person`, but rather they will become the same class (albeit with two different constructors).

More exactly, the methods and properties that you add to the prototype of `Employee` will be also visible for any `Person`. Note that classes in OOP should not affect their superclass in any way.

---

```
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

will create a new Object, similarly to

```
Employee.prototype = {};
Employee.prototype.__proto__ = Person.prototype
```

except `Object.create` (unlike `__proto__`) works in all browsers, or to

```
Employee.prototype = new Person();
```

except the constructor of `Person` may also set additional properties to `Employee.prototype` while `Object.create` will create an object without extra properties.

---

The infinite loop in your fiddle happens because `Employee.prototype.sayHi` calls `Person.prototype.sayHi`, but `Employee.prototype.sayHi` *is* `Person.prototype.sayHi`, and thus it calls *itself* (the original `Person.prototype.sayHi` was lost when you assigned to `Employee.prototype.sayHi`).

If `Employee.prototype === Person.prototype` then, neccessarily, `Employee.prototype.sayHi === Person.prototype.sayHi`.